# Rendering issues under Firefox

Tags: css, cross-browser

Under Chrome this is like this and how it is suppose to be :

[image]

However under firefox it goes like that :

[image]

[Here is a link to see it link](http://www.agencedevoyage.com/)

Does someone has any link to a page where are explained the differences between navigators and their fixes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `max-width: 70%` by `width: 70%` in this selector :

```
#miniMenu img { width: 70%; }
```

See this post on SO explaining issue on Firefox with max-width property : 
[Image mysteriously ignoring max-width in Firefox & IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550356/image-mysteriously-ignoring-max-width-in-firefox-ie)

Especially theses lines from @Boris Zbarsky answer :

> You have max-width: 100%, but 100% of what? Of the parent width,
>   right? But the parent is an inline-block (with class="sponsor") whose
>   width is not set, so its width depends on the children, and in
>   particular on the preferred width of the children.
>
> The layout of this styling is undefined in the CSS specification. In
>   particular, the intrinsic width of the kids in this case depends on
>   the width of the parent which in turn depends on the intrinsic width
>   of the kids. See
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float for the
>   relevant spec text and note all the "does not define" bits.

Comment: Great ! You're the one !